# How to use Taurus to modify a jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I'm trying out [taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) to run some existing jmeter scripts, setting various properties to local values.

I can use the `-gui` mode to load the modified script in the jmeter GUI and debug. However, I can't update this and replace the original file because Taurus has added two jtl data writers. I can suppress "Errors Writer" with e.g. `-o execution.0.write-xml-jtl=none`, but I can't see a way to suppress "KPI Writer". It's also possible further undesirable modifications have been made.

Is there a way to launch the GUI so that I can edit the original file, using the properties from the Taurus yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the original jmeter scripts through bzt however it is possible to manipulate few properties of the newly generated jmx file through the yml file. Modified jmx is a copy of original script where two Listeners (errors and kpi) and variables from the yml.

It now depends on what exactly are you looking to change?